# Difference between Sorgam (heaven) & Trishanku Sorgam (Heaven) - Anusham Star

Tags: vedas, puranas, advaita, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava

I've heard from one experience that one Mahaperiyava - The Great Sage of Kanchi saying that his highness's birth Star (Anusham) is special because it is not found in Trishanku sorgam.

I just want to know whether that's what he said. Can someone throw more light on this topic.